# trying to prove that a sequence to power of 2 converges too

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

If:   $$\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n=L$$

So: $$\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n^2=L^2$$

.....
my try to prove:

Let $\varepsilon>0$.

because $$\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n=L$$

so $$\forall\varepsilon>0,\exists N: \forall n>N:|a_n-L|<min\{1,  {\varepsilon\over 1+2|L|} \}$$

so $$\forall\varepsilon>0,\exists N: \forall n>N:$$

$$|a_n^2-L^2| = |a_n-L||(a_n-L+2L)|\le|a_n-L|(|a_n-L|+2|L|)<|a_n-L|(1+2|L|)<{\varepsilon\over 1+2|L|}(1+2|L|)=\varepsilon$$

...

please tell me if that acceptable,
thanks

Comment: It seems to be right. Also, you can prove that the product of convergent sequences converges to the product of the limits.

Comment: It looks fine to me.

Comment: Any more ideas...?